# Вхождение подстроки из множества подстрок

Tags: python, строки, подстрока

Как можно сделать условие компактнее и более удобным? Ведь у меня много таких строк, и если я буду продолжать также писать, то это будет длинное условие, и некрасиво будет смотреться.

```
if "string_1" in my_string or "string_2" in my_string or "string_3" in my_string or "string_4" in my_string...:
    continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте функцию [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). Она вернёт `True`, если хотя бы один из элементов, переданного ей итерируемого объекта, является истинным.

***Пример:***

```py
li = ['string_1', 'string_2', 'string_3', 'string_4']

if any(s in my_string for s in li):
    continue
```

Comment: `any(map(my_string.count, li))`

Comment: @user207200 Хорошо, но `count` тут излишен, достаточно `__contains__`

Comment: @CrazyElf согласен!

Answer (score 4):

"Функциональный" вариант с использованием `any` и метода строки `__contains__` - аналога `in`:

```
if any(map(my_string.__contains__, li)):
   continue
```